# Разрешения для фонарика в Android 6 и выше

Tags: android

Я далеко не специалист в Java. Пересмотрел десятки решений, но даже по аналогии не могу написать нужную мне строку кода. Помогите пожалуйста!

В манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

В MainActivity:

```
private static final int REQUEST_FLASHLIGHT = 1;

private static String[] PERMISSIONS_FLASHLIGHT = {
            Manifest.permission.FLASHLIGHT
};

public static void verifyCameraPermissions(Activity activity) {
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.FLASHLIGHT);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_FLASHLIGHT,
                REQUEST_FLASHLIGHT
        );
    }
}
```

Ну и напоследок в самом FlashlightController.java:

```
private void startDevice() throws CameraAccessException {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {

            ***Строка запроса разрешения***

            return;
            }
        mCameraManager.openCamera(getCameraId(), mCameraListener, mHandler);
    }
```

Вот эту эту ***Строку и не могу написать.
Перепробовал десятки вариантов - студия красным орёт Cannot resilve symbol, а я не могу исправить из-за недостатка знаний и опыта.
Так же не уверен - везде ли правильно указаны CAMERA и FLASHLIGHT.

Вычитал, что моя проблема в том, что напрямую запрашивать разрешения можно только из Activity или Fragment, а мне нужно из FlashlightController.java. Как это сделать?

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Я в этом более менее чем уверен. Вы не можете вызвать разрешение из класса FlashlightController, по той причине, что нет доступа к Activity, Context. Попробуйте, передать необходимые ссылки. Создайте конструктор `FlashlightController(Context ctx, Activity act)` а здесь прописать так `if (act.checkSelfPermission(ctx, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)`

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример из рабочего приложения:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER_RESUME = 2;
    private ImageButton imgbtn;
    private Camera camera;
    private Camera.Parameters param;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    private boolean on = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
        imgbtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        hasFlash = getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
        if (!hasFlash) {
            finish();
        }
        getPermis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!on) {
            turnOn();
        } else {
            turnOff();
        }
    }

    private void turnOn() {
        if (camera != null && param != null) {

            param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(param);
            camera.startPreview();
            imgbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_on);
            on = true;
        }
    }

    private void turnOff() {

        if (camera != null && param != null) {

            param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(param);
            camera.stopPreview();
            imgbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_off);
            on = false;
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
            imgbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_off);
            on = false;
        }
    }

    private void getPermis() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                camera = Camera.open();
                param = camera.getParameters();


            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER);
            }
        } else {
            camera = Camera.open();
            param = camera.getParameters();

        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER && grantResults.length == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                getPermis();


            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        releaseCamera();
        finish();
    }
}
```

А так в Манифесте:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxxxxxxx.flashlight">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name=".flashlight"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name="com.xxxxxxxxx.flashlight.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Говорю же - я очень слаб в Java. Я не в состоянии переделать программу под ваш пример. Да и к тому же, в моей программе фонарик работает до Андроид 6, а начав её кромсать, я рискую сломать что есть, так и не создав что нужно. У меня запуск фонарика описан в отдельном файле FlashlightController.java и проблема видимо в том, что я не могу в нём использовать переменные, которые определены в MainActivity, точнее - REQUEST_FLASHLIGHT. Студия сразу, красным "Cannot resilve symbol". Мне нужно дописать всего одну строку запроса разрешения - не хочет работать из другого файла.

Comment: Вычитал, что моя проблема в том, что напрямую запрашивать разрешения можно только из Activity или Fragment, а мне нужно из FlashlightController.java. Как это сделать?